# Why the copied HTML doesn't look like the original HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I copied the generated source code (`View Source -> View Generated Source` in the Firefox Web Developer Toolbar) of Google's [Keyword Tool page](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1908280996&__c=3148491556) to a new HTML file.

But, when I open this new file, some of the items looks stretched for some reason:

[image]

The original website looks like this:

[image]

I guess that Google create some elements and set various attributes using Javascript, but I copied the page **after** it has been generated. So, why is this difference?

---

**UPDATE 1**

The only JS/CSS file, which is not given as a full path, is:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/cues/cues.js">
```

I tried replace this with:

```
<script language="javascript">
  Contents of '/cues/cues.js' here
</script>
```

but it didn't help.

---

**UPDATE 2**

In the browser's error console I found the following 2 errors:

```
Error: com_google_ads_apps_servers_cues_CuesRelease is not defined
Source File: https://adwords.google.com/cues/768DAEDDB2193AB5B05B9C6A01394D78.cache.js
Line: 1

Error: com_google_ads_apps_targetingideas_client_TargetingIdeas is not defined
Source File: https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/756D6AF3BB4DD4A68315E34F50C2BC7E.cache.js
Line: 1
```

Any ideas why these errors appear?

---

**UPDATE 3**

Apparently, the reason is that the `DOCTYPE` declaration is missing. After I added `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the stretched version, it solved the problem. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Do you have all the CSS that goes with the original page?

Comment: Did you copy ALL of the css as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save a page, you only get the version of HTML served from the server in its original form. Any mods to the DOM made after load using JS will not be part of the save.

**EDIT**

I could not trace out the exact reason for the error as the code is really cryptic! In any case, if all you want is to be able to reproduce the exact page offline, then you can do a 'save page as..' from your browser (choose web page, complete). I tried this with FF as well as Chrome and it is working fine in both cases. While opening the saved page, it might be best not to use IE as its a certified choker when it comes to even the slightest error in code. :)

The most likely reason for the error is an cross-domain AJAX security exception (fired when the calling client side script and called server side script are from different domains). The 2 variables namely, com_google_ads_apps_servers_cues_CuesRelease and com_google_ads_apps_targetingideas_client_TargetingIdeas seems to be initialized using the return of some AJAX call (which couldn't execute bcoz of the secu excep), and as a result remain as undefined.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's error console? Do check if you have a security exception listed there.

Comment: You are right. There are some errors. Please see "Update 2". Any ideas why these errors appear?

Comment: I could not trace out the exact reason for the error as the code is really cryptic! In any case, if all you want is to be able to reproduce the exact page offline, then you can do a 'save page as..' from your browser (choose web page, complete). I tried this with FF as well as Chrome and it is working fine in both cases. While opening the saved page, it might be best not to use IE as its a certified choker when it comes to even the slightest error in code. :)

Comment: The most likely reason for the error is an cross-domain AJAX security exception (fired when the calling client side script and called server side script are from different domains). The 2 variables namely, com_google_ads_apps_servers_cues_CuesRelease and com_google_ads_apps_targetingideas_client_TargetingIdeas seems to be initialized using the return of some AJAX call (which couldn't execute bcoz of the secu excep), and as a result remain as undefined.

Comment: Interesting... When I do 'save page as..', as you suggested, I still see the two errors above. However, the page is **not** stretched. The question is what is different in this page so it doesn't look stretched?

Answer (score 1):

You must be missing some `css` and `js` which is not on the page but referred from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is that the CSS and the corresponding images that might be referred within it are not getting applied correctly.
Check the paths of the CSS and for the images (background) within the CSS...You might need to correct the paths to fix the issue.